# Null Pointer Exception on SimpleTimestampFormat.parse(SimpleTimestampFormat.java:347)

Tags: nullpointerexception, pentaho, simpledateformat

I am trying to load a file into an application but while loading it throws an error

```
2022/11/03 19:35:49 - ExtractRowDataTimeStamp.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2022/11/03 19:35:49 - ExtractRowDataTimeStamp.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by buildguy) : java.lang.NullPointerException
2022/11/03 19:35:49 - ExtractRowDataTimeStamp.0 -       at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.timestamp.SimpleTimestampFormat.parse(SimpleTimestampFormat.java:347)
2022/11/03 19:35:49 - ExtractRowDataTimeStamp.0 -       at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:364)
2022/11/03 19:35:49 - ExtractRowDataTimeStamp.0 -       at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.timestamp.SimpleTimestampFormat.parse(SimpleTimestampFormat.java:449)
2022/11/03 19:35:49 - ExtractRowDataTimeStamp.0 -       at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaTimestamp.convertStringToTimestamp(ValueMetaTimestamp.java:256)
2022/11/03 19:35:49 - ExtractRowDataTimeStamp.0 -       at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaTimestamp.convertData(ValueMetaTimestamp.java:418)
2022/11/03 19:35:49 - ExtractRowDataTimeStamp.0 -       at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.selectvalues.SelectValues.metadataValues(SelectValues.java:328)
2022/11/03 19:35:49 - ExtractRowDataTimeStamp.0 -       at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.selectvalues.SelectValues.processRow(SelectValues.java:381)
2022/11/03 19:35:49 - ExtractRowDataTimeStamp.0 -       at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2022/11/03 19:35:49 - ExtractRowDataTimeStamp.0 -       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2022/11/03 19:35:49 - DataValidatorSequential.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=9, W=9, U=0, E=0)
2022/11/03 19:35:49 - AVIVAPolicyHome - ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2022/11/03 19:35:49 - updateRiesgoHogar.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection.
2022/11/03 19:35:49 - DataValidatorRow11.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=51, W=0, U=0, E=0)
2022/11/03 19:35:49 - deleteCustomerRemovedFromPersona.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection.
```

What could be the possible resolution?

Comment: Roughly two possible explanations: Either there’s a bug in the data you are trying to load, or there’s a bug in Apache Pentaho-kettle.

Comment: 12:40:10,056 INFO  [KarafBoot] Checking to see if org.pentaho.clean.karaf.cache is enabled
12:40:10,135 ERROR [KarafBoot] Error starting Karaf
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.pentaho.platform.osgi.ServerSocketBasedKarafInstanceResolver.assignAvailableCacheFolderForType(ServerSocketBasedKarafInstanceResolver.java:97)
What this error signifies? @OleV.V.

Comment: I don’t know Pentaho so don’t know much about that error. Most of what I do know is here: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)